# vi script that recursively copies files from a source directory to a target directory

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement, vi

I need to use an if statement that will copy files from one directory to a new one. I am extremely new to this so any information that could possibly be explained would be great. The only thing I have so far is:

```
#! /bin/bash

src=$1
dest=$2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps you out.

I prefer to  use more descriptive variable names: it will help you when you come back in 3-6 months and don't remember what you did.

```
#!/bin/bash

sourceDirectory=$1
destinationDirectory=$2

# 
# $ [[ -d $destinationDirectory ]] && echo "Directory exists" || echo "Directory does not exist"

# $ [[ -d /var/logs ]] && echo "Directory exists" || echo "Directory does not exist"

#
if [[ -d $destinationDirectory ]];
then
   echo "Directory $destinationDirectory exists"
else
   echo "Directory $destinationDirectory does not exist"
   mkdir -p  "$destinationDirectory" 
fi

cp -var "$sourceDirectory" "$destinationDirectory"
```

Comment: thank you! just to add to this he said to use: $(find $src)

to get a list of the files and subdirectories under $src including $src itself....... but im not sure where to add this in?

Comment: sorry for all these extra questions. How would i also check to see if the two arguments are directories?

Comment: if [[ -d $destinationDirectory ]];
Line checks to make sure its a directory.  you would have to do the same for the source directory variable